# Unable to upload file in s3 bucket using laravel 5.7- Argument 1 passed to League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter:

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload the image to the s3 bucket but unable to do so. Getting the following
error:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, file_get_contents($file));

Argument 1 passed to League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\S3\S3ClientInterface, instance of Aws\S3\S3Client given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php on line 208 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to League\\Flysystem\\AwsS3v3\\AwsS3Adapter::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\\S3\\S3ClientInterface, instance of Aws\\S3\\S3Client given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php on line 208 at /var/www/html/vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/src/AwsS3Adapter.php:85)
```

My composer.json contains:

```
...
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.0",
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
"league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "1.0",
...
```

My filesystems.php:

```
 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url'    => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],
```

AWS s3 user permission - AmazonS3FullAccess

AWS s3 bucket - policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The minimum required version of aws-php-sdk should be 3.20.0

Comment: I changed the version, still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for more than 4 days, I removed both
`"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.0"`, and `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0", "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "1.0",` from composer.json and run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

After that, it worked :)

Comment: I found conflict, using laravel 8, back to `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"` :(

Comment: composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3.
This does not work for me, I am stuck here, anyone has a solution?

currently this is installed.
league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "1.0

Comment: I struggled with s3 using laravel 9 and "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0" , downgrading to 1.0 fixed my issues specifically with using storeAs

Answer (score 3):

I faced the issue on **Laravel 5.8**, local and AWS s3 bucket was failed to create the resource and laravel backups.

please run this command, that will fix it.

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:~1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was to update two lines in this file - **/vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/src/AwsS3Adapter.php**

**OLD:**
use Aws\S3Client;
use Aws\S3ClientInterface;

**NEW:**
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\S3ClientInterface;

Comment: you should never make changes in vendor files