# Lumen 8.x filesystem not working. Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, filesystems, lumen

I have installed these two packages

```
"league/flysystem": "^2.0",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.0"
```

Added these codes in `app/bootstrap.php` file

```
   $app->singleton('filesystem', function ($app) {
      return $app->loadComponent(
          'filesystems',
           Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
           'filesystem'
        );
   });

  $app->register(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class);
```

Also registered the config file `filesystems.php`

```
$app->configure('filesystems');
```

`spaces` config in `filesystems.php`

```
'spaces' => [
  'driver' => 's3',
  'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
  'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
  'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
  'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
  'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
 ]
```

I want to read a file from the storage

```
$file = Storage::disk('spaces')->get($existing_path);
```

Now I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found (Laravel + Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619465/class-league-flysystem-awss3v3-awss3adapter-not-found-laravel-heroku)

Comment: Can you try deleting your vendor folder and running `composer install`?

Comment: Tried but didn't worked @Eden Moshe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193773/unable-to-upload-file-in-s3-bucket-using-laravel-5-7-argument-1-passed-to-leagu):
removed both `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.0"`, and `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"`, "`league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "1.0"`, from composer.json

and run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

Comment: This is my composer.json:
...
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "flipbox/lumen-generator": "^8.2",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.0"
    },
...
But it doesn't work

Comment: What error do you get?
What version of PHP are you running on?
Can you put all the composer.json?

Comment: It turned out it was because I set "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.0"  instead of "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"