# League\\Flysystem\\AwsS3v3\\AwsS3Adapter::__construct(): Argument #1 ($client) must be of type Aws\\S3Client, Aws\\S3\\S3Client given

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-8, laravel-filesystem

I have installed the s3 flysystem package by running the following composer command in my `Laravel 8` project

```
composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"
```

and tried to store a file from the request as

```
$imageName = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
```

I got the following error

> League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter::__construct(): Argument #1
> ($client) must be of type Aws\S3Client, Aws\S3\S3Client given, called
> in
> D:\Projects\Rescale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php
> on line 229

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to upload file in s3 bucket using laravel 5.7- Argument 1 passed to League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193773/unable-to-upload-file-in-s3-bucket-using-laravel-5-7-argument-1-passed-to-leagu)

Answer (score 21):

So it seems ThePHPLeague Flysystem major version got updated (to v2) thus breaking a lot of stuff since latest Laravel depends on "^1.1" (see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/composer.json#L27).

I've had this error, so my workaround is to use a specific version instead.

---

1. Go to composer.json and use latest v1 (see: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/tags).

```
- "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
+ "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "1.0.29",
```

2. Run `composer update` and let composer update your dependencies.

Comment: If the version was specified as ^1.0 then the fact that the package had a v2.0 released would make no difference. Caret means it will not change major versions.